# Mac Keystrokes for screen capture while VPN remote to Windows 7 work computer

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, vpn

I am using a Mac with OS X 10.9 to VPN remote to a Windows 7 Machine at work. I need to take a screen capture of another applications window on the work computer to transfer into Adobe Photoshop.

However, I cannot find the proper keystroke combinations to screen capture from my Mac keyboard (does not have number pad).

Comment: What is a "VPN Remote"? VPN is a networking technology, not a remote control software.

Comment: Have you tried the usual Mac keystroke to capture the screen -- I don't recall exactly what they are, but you can look them up in OSX's Help.

Answer (score 0):

Command Shift 4 will allow you to outline where you want to create a screen capture. It will auto save to the desktop. Once you press the combo of buttons ( Shift Command 4 ) click and drag the cross airs across the desired screen area. 
Viola